# Launch AVD manager from command line

Tags: applications, windows, command-line, avd-manager

- I'm on Windows 10.
- Android studio version 2.3.3

How can I launch the AVD Manager with-out opening the Android Studio and creating a project ?

I remember it was possible for earlier version of Android Studio. I found the `avdmanager.bat` file in `Android\Sdk\tools\bin` but running it won't launch the avdmanger UI that we get from the Android Studio.

Anyone here faced the same issue and found a way to launch AVD manager from command line ?

Comment: [This Q/A](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221678/how-can-i-launch-avd-manager-without-opening-or-creating-a-project-in-android-st) might be relevant to the OP or anyone else looking for how to open the AVD Manager graphical user interface without having to create or open a project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 15):

## There is no way to launch AVD manager from cmdline (It is deprecated)

There is no way to launch AVD from cmd line. But you can use `avdmanager` cmdline tool to create, delete, move, list & edit your AVD.

The `avdmanager` tool is provided in the "Android SDK Coommand-line Tools" package and is located in `android-sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\avdmanager.bat`

To read more about cmdline avdmanager [read this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager)

### To launch emulator from cmdline

Add the path first

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
```

Your path may be different update accordingly

An then run the cmd

```
emulator -avd "avd_name"
```

Reference
[Android developers launch avd from cmd line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html)

Comment: You may also wish to mention that the user can add the directory path variable, or perfoming this command in `\sdk\tools` folder

Comment: @Rajendran Thanks for the answer. But this is not what I'm looking for I want to launch the AVD manager UI not the emulator.

Comment: The thing that you are asking is impossible now bcuz those cmds are depricated and removed in latest version.

Comment: For folks arguing that the answer doesn't answer "how to launch avd manager gui using cmd", Rajendran has argued that it is "not possible" and provided an alternative to solution sought. If you folks disagree, then please provide an alternative as a proper answer which mentions the steps that would launch "avd manager ui using cmd" and that too "without launching Android studio at all".