# How can I launch AVD Manager without opening or creating a project in Android Studio?

Tags: avd-manager, android-studio

Sometimes I just want to open the AVD Manager GUI that is reachable from Android Studio's Tools menu, but without having to start Android Studio and creating or opening a project.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it doesn't seem possible to get around having to start Android Studio, it is possible to start the AVD Manager without creating or opening a project.

On the launch screen that opens when no project is open in Android Studio, the AVD Manager is available under the Configure menu.

[image]