# Changing Wear OS AVD build properties

Tags: android-emulator, android-wear, builds

I'm trying to get hold of one specific app: [LV Watch Faces 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sfeir.lvmh.watchface2). I cannot find this anywhere. It's possible to extract it from an LV Wear OS watch, but I don't have them. I got an idea, maybe it's possible to change the device name/model on the Wear OS emulator for an app to appear on the emulator's Google Play Store.

I tried changing `build.prop` that's located in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-28\android-wear\x86`, but it seems like it didn't work (it shows the same default name `sdk_gwear_x86`)in the Settings)

[image: Settings]

Could anyone help with changing Wear OS's AVD build properties or generally suggest - does this idea make sense (changing those properties for having hardware limited store apps to appear).

Comment: Play store usually does not only use the device name for filtering. Additionally you can set-up an app to require certain features and system libraries to be present. Both can be manufacturer or even device specific. Therefore the chance of being able to download a (wear) app by just forging the device name is very very low.

Comment: @Robert Thank you, Robert! But I'd like to try anyways. I'm actually reading your instruction how to launch an avd manager (apparently, I need it to use commands for changing props). I don't get it. I open powershell in the emulator path and avd commands don't work. How would I open it?

Comment: @robert https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182920/launch-avd-manager-from-command-line

Comment: Hi, perhaps this is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919) (installing specific watch face vs changing Wear OS AVD's build properties), though Y is also a valid question. However, for tackling the X directly, have you considered alternative sources/mirror sites to download the APK (we can't guarantee its safety, but just in case...)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Hey, it really is, I'm sorry. I tried almost every mirror site - they don't have this apk.

Comment: I just tried searching for `"com.sfeir.lvmh.watchface2" apk` and while there are some sites, I guess you're right that they don't actually have the APK due to it being a Watch OS app...

Comment: @AndrewT. They don't.